# Angular2 - nativeElement of ElementRef is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an `viewport: ElementRef` object in a component, which I can log and see values for all of its properties. I can see that there is an array of `children` of length 3, and I need to access `children[1]`.

While logging the value of `viewport` allows me to see all of its properties, when I try to access `viewport.nativeElement` I get undefined. Therefore when I try to access `viewport.nativeElement.children[1]` I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
```

I am trying to figure out:

1. Why the `nativeElement` value is undefined when I can clearly see that the ElementRef has a value
2. If there is a different way to access properties such as `getBoundingClientRect()` without using `nativeElement`

Comment: Did you wait until rendering was complete before trying to access the elements

Comment: related -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383608/cannot-read-property-nativeelement-of-undefined

Comment: @adeneo the function that I'm using to access these properties is called in ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: Try ngAfterViewChecked() instead

Comment: check that you are not inside a callback or a subscription since the references to "this" can change due to being in other context. Sometimes it happens