# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined got erroe

Tags: typescript

Hi I am working on Angular 7 project and i have implemented a div show hide functionality using Angular @ViewChild and nativeElement but getting below error:-
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.

I have tried to understand and search online but not got any solution. Below is my code so any one can review my code and suggest some changes in my code so i can solve my issue. Thanks!

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";    
import { Theme } from "./../../../model/themes/themes.model";    
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material";    
import { BaseResponse } from "./../../../model/BaseResponse.model";    
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  SecurityContext,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  Renderer2,
  Directive,
  Input,
  HostListener,
  Inject,
  ElementRef as ErrorProneElementRef
} from "@angular/core";    
import { RedisCacheService } from "../../services/redis-cache.service";    
import { UserSessionActions } from "src/app/model/user-session-actions/UserSessionActions.model";    
import { Router, NavigationStart } from "@angular/router";    
import { ChannelService } from "src/app/app-modules/channels/channel.service";    
import { CommonDialogComponent } from "../../common-dialog/common-dialog.component";    
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";    
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";    
import { CommonService } from "../../services/common.service";    
import * as fromLogin from "../../../store/auth/login/login.actions";    

@Component({
  selector: "app-header",
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./header.component.scss"]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  //_profilePanel: boolean = false;
  _themePanel: boolean = false;
  _modalData: string;
  _stateData: any;

  loggedInUserName: string;
  loggedInUserEmail: string;

  _jsonDarkMenu = "assets/json/Themes/darkTheme.json";
  _jsonLightMenu = "assets/json/Themes/lightTheme.json";
  _jsonDefaultTheme = "assets/json/Themes/defaultStandardTheme.json";

  subscription: Subscription;

  darkThemeArray: Theme[] = [];
  lightThemeArray: Theme[] = [];
  defaultTheme: Theme[] = [];
  _userProfileView: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild("clickOutsideCloseBtn") clickOutsideCloseBtn: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("userProfile") userProfile: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild("themePanelShowHide") themePanelShowHide: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("themeCloseBtn") themeCloseBtn: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild("header-disableProfileIcon") headerPreferenceToggle: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("header-user-profile-section") preferenceMenu: ElementRef;
  dialogRef: any;

  constructor(
    private _redisCacheService: RedisCacheService,
    private router: Router,
    private _channelService: ChannelService,
    private _dialog: MatDialog,
    private store: Store<any>,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private commonService: CommonService,
    myElement: ElementRef
  ) {



    /**
     * This events get called by all clicks on the page
     */
    this.renderer.listen("window", "click", (e: Event) => {
      /**
       * Only run when toggleButton is not clicked
       * If we don't check this, all clicks (even on the toggle button) gets into this
       * section which in the result we might never see the menu open!
       * And the menu itself is checked here, and it's where we check just outside of
       * the menu and button the condition abbove must close the menu
       */
      if (
        !this.clickOutsideCloseBtn.nativeElement.contains(e.target) &&
        !this.userProfile.nativeElement.contains(e.target)
      ) {
        this._userProfileView = false;
      }
    });

    this.renderer.listen("window", "click", (e: Event) => {
      /**
       * Only run when toggleButton is not clicked
       * If we don't check this, all clicks (even on the toggle button) gets into this
       * section which in the result we might never see the menu open!
       * And the menu itself is checked here, and it's where we check just outside of
       * the menu and button the condition abbove must close the menu
       */
      if (
        !this.themePanelShowHide.nativeElement.contains(e.target) &&
        !this.themeCloseBtn.nativeElement.contains(e.target)
      ) {
        this._themePanel = false;
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * This events get called by all clicks on the page
   */

  ngAfterViewInit() {}

  htmlContent: string;
  private themeWrapper = document.querySelector("body");
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  }
```

HTML Code:-

```
<div>
      <div
        class="header-user-profile-section"
        #userProfile
        *ngIf="_userProfileView"
      >
        <ul class="header-user-profile-menu">
          <li class="header-pad-bottom-0">
            <span class="header-user-pofile-img"
              ><img
                class="header-profile-icon"
                src="../../../../assets/images/common/user-profile-placeholder.jpg"
                alt="profile-img"
            /></span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="header-username-txt">
              {{ _stateData.userDetails.userFullName }}
            </p>
            <p class="header-secondary-text">
              {{ _stateData.userDetails.userId }}
            </p>
          </li>
          <li class="header-logout-btn ">
            <button class="hb-btn-transparent" (click)="_logoutClickHandler()">
              Logout
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'native-element' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383608/cannot-read-property-native-element-of-undefined)

Comment: NO. it did not helped. Please give some other suggestion.

Comment: Hi, any update on this?